# Finding duplicates, but including duplicates and other columns in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to find duplicates on two different columns in my table, but also include other column values in results as well. Such as the row id. I AM USING SQL SERVER 2012

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT rowID, appID, spNumber, spName, date_submitted 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY appID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The problem with the above query is that it groups all duplicates into one row. I want all the duplicates to display. I also want to find all duplicates of the appID AND the spNumber fields. This is how I want my resulting data to look like. I ONLY WANT TO DISPLAY ROWS WHERE BOTH THE APPID AND THE SPNUMBER ARE DUPLICATES.

```
rowID   |   appID  |  spNumber  |  spName  |  date_submitted
-------------------------------------------------------------
  34    |    832   |     1      | Bob Smith|   01/01/2010
  36    |    832   |     1      | Joe Bob  |   05/01/2010
  54    |    901   |     2      | Sue Joe  |   03/01/2010
  57    |    901   |     2      | Pat Joh  |   04/01/2010
  59    |    901   |     2      | Tim Sue  |   03/01/2010
  64    |    951   |     1      | Jim Bob  |   06/01/2010
  67    |    951   |     1      | Sam Sue  |   09/01/2010
```

Comment: This query will not run on SQL Server, are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER() will do this for you. Just make sure to select the rows with a higher row number than 1 and you will only get the duplicates based on the two columns in your PARTITION BY

Example:

```
SELECT rowID, appID, spNumber, spName, date_submitted 
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY appID, spNumber ORDER BY appID) AS rn
    FROM myTable t
) x
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
SELECT rowID, appID, spNumber, spName, date_submitted 
FROM myTable
JOIN (
    SELECT appID
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY appID, spNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dups ON myTable.appID = dups.appID AND dups.spNumber = myTable.spNumber
```

Comment: This does not work. It does not give me the rows where both the appID and the spNumber

Comment: Ah, I was going on your example there and didn't read that it was for both.  That adjustment is easy, and I've edited it to show.

Comment: Also, are you using mysql?  I thought when my first reply was on here it was tagged as mysql, but as someone else mentioned it isn't tagged as such now.  The tag sql-server is for Microsoft's SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregates it's simple:

```
with cte as 
 (
   SELECT rowID, appID, spNumber, spName, date_submitted,
      count(*) over (partition by appID) as cnt -- count per appID
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY appID
 )
SELECT  rowID, appID, spNumber, spName, date_submitted
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
```